# Using <C-h> and <C-S-h> separately

Tags: key-bindings

I want to make separate bindings for `<C-h>` and `<C-S-h>`. For example:

```
noremap <C-h> <C-w>h
noremap <C-j> <C-w>j
noremap <C-k> <C-w>k
noremap <C-l> <C-w>l

noremap <C-S-h> :vertical resize -2<CR>
noremap <C-S-j> :resize -2<CR>
noremap <C-S-k> :resize +2<CR>
noremap <C-S-l> :vertical resize +2<CR>
```

However, with my settings, pressing `<C-h>` and `<C-S-H>` both trigger `:vertical resize -2<CR>` which should be mapped to only `<C-S-h>`.

How can I map `<C-h>` and `<C-S-h>` separately?

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible as Vim doesn't "see" `<C-S-h>`.

Try the following:

Open Vim and enter insert mode. Noch press `<C-v>` followed by `<C-h>`. Vim
will insert `^H` (highlighted in light blue by default). So Vim got `<C-h>`.

Now press `<C-v>` followed by `<C-S-h>` and Vim will again insert `^H`.

So from Vims point of view, `<C-h>` and `<C-S-h>` are identical.

The reason is Vims origin as a terminal based program. Those terminals only
supports "simple" control-character combinations.

You can use the test described above ( `<C-v>` ...) with any key combination
you would like to map.

PS: On my setup with Linux and GNOME-Terminal, Vim doesn't see `<C-S-h>` at
all, as the key combination is used by GNOME-Terminal.

---

Updated after the comments from Christian Brabandt and user938271:

Your mapping works with GVim (tested with 8.2.869).

Depending on the terminal emulator it might be possible for Vim to get the
`<C-S-h>`.

The XTerm terminal emulator supports a option called `modifyOtherKeys`. With
it the terminal supports additional key combos like `<C-S-h>`.

When XTerm is correctly configured, the mapping you describe work as expected.
Tested with Vim 8.2.869 and xterm 351.

Read about it in `:h modifyOtherKeys`.

Notes:

- I don't know which other terminal emulators support `modifyOtherKeys`.
- `modifyOtherKeys` is not supported by GNOME-Terminal (see this [bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=477068) )
- First mention of `modifyOtherKeys` in a Vim commit was version 8.1.2134 (Oct 2019)

Conclusion: Your mapping will work with the right terminal emulator and
configuration and a up-to-date Vim, but I would not rely on this, as it is not
widely portable.

Comment: That is not completely correct nowadays. With `modifyOtherKeys`, vim can distinguish `<c-h>` and `<c-s-h>`. However I think currently only xterm supports this (and perhaps the gui). gnome-terminal (or vte) has some wishlist bugs about supporting `modifyOtherKeys`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I played around with `modifyOtherKeys` in xterm. It sends esc-sequences for something like `<C-.>` or `<C-S-.>`, but `<C-h>` and `<C-S-h>` both send `<C-h>` (tried other chars as well).

Comment: You can also distinguish the inserted presses with `ga`. bestasciitable.com is good too :)

Comment: @Christian Brabandt is right.  Vim can distinguish `C-h` from `C-S-h` in a terminal which supports the modifyOtherKeys feature such as xterm.  xterm sends `^[[27;5;104~` for `C-h` and `^[[27;6;72~` for `C-S-h` which are different sequences.  [Tested on Vim 8.2.0869 and xterm 322](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1FFi.gif).

Comment: To be sure that modifyOtherKeys is enabled, press `C-S-v` followed by `C-v` in insert mode; if you only get a literal `^V`, then the feature is not enabled.  Note that `C-S-v` is often used in a terminal key binding to paste the clipboard; if that's the case, you may need to temporarily disable the key binding.

Comment: @user938271 Retested and got it working. Thanks.